# Multi-level grid hierarchy - grandparent data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

At the `transaction` level of the hierarchy, I need access to a value from the `#grid` data. Can this be passed as a parameter or must I traverse the DOM using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        ...
        detailInit: summary
    });
});

function summary(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        ...
        detailInit: transactions
    });
}

function tranasctions(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the `detailInit` event only provides `masterRow` property in its first argument object, which stands for the parent expanded row. So I'm afraid you'll have to *traverse* it. What I suggest is to store the `masterRow` in a `data` attribute in the second detail grid in order to find it in the last level:

Second level grid:

```
$(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    // settings ...
}).data("master", e.masterRow);
```

This will create a data attribute named "master" with the first expanded row. Then in the third level you can retrieve it with:

```
var root = $(e.masterRow).closest(".k-detail-cell").data("master");
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UwuXi)**</kbd>

Comment: Many thanks for the reply - very useful. I've amended your demo to include a tabstrip http://dojo.telerik.com/UwuXi/3. Now `root` returns `undefined`. Any idea why?

Comment: @user1405195 that is because you have changed the element which the last grid is created, in this case `.people` element. You have to change the source of `root` as well. http://dojo.telerik.com/UwuXi/4